# remove top and left axis in a matplotlib plot using a style sheet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use a matplotlib style sheet for removing the upper and right ticks.

```
import matplot.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False) 
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
```

What are the commands I have to use in the style sheet to get the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I struggled with this question too, here's my answer. Add the following lines to your stylesheet:

```
axes.spines.left   : True
axes.spines.bottom : True
axes.spines.top    : False
axes.spines.right  : False
```

Removing the ticks should be obsolete afterwards, but you can still play with this (skip these lines or set to false to remove the ticks):

```
xtick.top  : True
ytick.right: True
```

As far as I understood, it is not possible to specify options in a stylesheet that are not in your matplotlibrc file. So if these keys are not specified in the matplotlibrc, this solution will not work, and you should consider updating matplotlib.